# APK split by density still contains all resources

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I decided to try apk sliptting to reduce the size of my apk. I added the following to my gradle build file

```
splits {

    // Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
    density {

        // Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
        enable true

        // Specifies a list of screen densities Gradle should not create multiple APKs for.
        exclude "ldpi"

        // Specifies a list of compatible screen size settings for the manifest.
        compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal'
    }
}
```

This successfully generates separate apks for the various densities. However, I noticed that all of the apks were the same size, none of them were smaller than the universal apk. So, I loaded one (app-hdpi-release.apk) into the apk analyzer and found that it contained all resources. None were stripped out.

So effectively all the config did was to generate the same apk with different filenames. Am I missing something? Are there any other build options that could potentially be blocking the resources being removed?

Comment: Are you sure to have the resources splitted in the drawable-xxx folders correctly?

Comment: Yes, and they work correctly too. I have tested this by marking the different density versions of an image with different colours, and checking that the appropriate ones display on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

I did some hit and trial and finally it accepted. Before I was splitting on the basis of screen densities ONLY. Then I added the tag $compatibleScreens$ and it worked.

Here is the final split block-

```
android {
  ...
  splits {

    density {
      enable true

      reset()
      include "mdpi", "hdpi", "xhdpi",     "xxhdpi"

      // This is the line of code which got it right
      compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
    }
  }
}
```