# Android Density Split Not Working

Tags: android, gradle, apk

My app includes a lot of images so currently the signed APK is > 100mb (around 115mb) even with optimized images. I want to use a density split to generate density-specific builds. I am currently including the following in my gradle file but the produced APKs are all the same size and still include all resources.

```
// Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
density {

    // Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
    enable true

    // Specifies a list of compatible screen size settings for the manifest.
    compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
}
```

I noticed that someone else has experienced the same issue but no one has replied. I wanted to comment on the post but my reputation is not high enough: [APK split by density still contains all resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908387/apk-split-by-density-still-contains-all-resources)

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT below are two screenshots comparing the hdpi release build and the mdpi release build. You can clearly see they are the same size:

[image: hdpi]

[image: mdpi]

[image: compare hdpi with mdpi]

Comment: Are you using Flavors? I did some testing on some of my apps and the ones were I was using flavors this didn't work, but on other that dind't had any flavor it worked

Comment: No I am not using flavors on this app

Comment: Can you post the print screen of the comparison of 2 of the generated apk's? Using the analyze apk feature and comparing it to another one?

Comment: @NunoGomes I attached two screenshots. Analyzing the APK shows that they have the same exact contents, which each build having all density resources.

Comment: @Antimatéria it appears I accidentally tagged someone else. Not sure how that happened

Comment: I did some tests on several of my apps and the split did work, I changed the buildToolsVersion and gradle version and it still worked, I cant find a solution to this :/

Can you double check if your drawables are correct? In the different density folders and with the correct name?

Comment: I ended up getting the density split to work using Android Studio 3 Beta. I made a new git branch for me to toy with Android Studio 3. I think the underlying issue may have been with the retrolambda plugin that I was using in Android Studio 2 in order to use Java 8 but I am not certain.

Comment: i also facing the very same issue, and it's not working both on android studio and manually execute gradle command :|

Answer (score 2):

finally i solved this issue

in my case, i had to remove `resConfigs` on `defaultConfig` block on application gradle script

```
defaultConfig {
    resConfigs "en", "id" //remove this line
    //your other implementation
}
```

i don't know why, but it seems somehow `resConfigs` break apk split

Answer (score 0):

```
density {
  enable true
  reset()
  include "mdpi", "hdpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi",......
}
```

Add reset() and include in your code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a bug with Android Studio 2 but I got it to work with Android Studio 3.

Originally I was thinking it may have been an issue with the retrolambda plugin but I'm not positive.